# concurrent access SQLite Da

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, concurrency

I´m developing an app with 3 parts: 
- JavaFX Desktop app.
- Java Server WebApp
- AndroidApp

I´m using Hibernate for mapping a SQLite Database.

But when the desktop app is open and try to insert a new ibject from the AndroidApp throug the Server it gives me an error: `java.sql.SQLException: database is locked`

My hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:grainsa_provisional.sqlite</property>
    <property name="connection.username"></property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>
```

And my "Objects Manager",the same way in the Server and in the Desktop  by example:

```
private Session mSession;
private Transaction mTransaction;

private void initQuery() throws HibernateException {
    mSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    mTransaction = mSession.beginTransaction();
}

private void manejaExcepcion(HibernateException hibernateException) {
    mTransaction.rollback();
    throw new HibernateException("ha ocurrido un error con la Base de Datos!!!", hibernateException);
}


public Conductor selectConductorByID(Integer id) {
    Conductor conductor = new Conductor();
    try{
        initQuery();
        conductor = (Conductor) mSession.get(Conductor.class, id);
    } catch (HibernateException e){
        manejaExcepcion(e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        mSession.close();
    }
    return conductor;
}
```

If you need more information please ask!

What i´m doing wrong?

Thanks everyone and sorry about my english!

Edit: ím thinking to change the acces mode of mi desktop JavaFX app to make the query through the server, but it will take me alot of time, and i do not think that is the best way to do it..

Edit2:
This is the right way to open, make query and close the conexion to the databasa to lock/query/unlock?

```
private void initQuery() throws HibernateException {
    mSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    mTransaction = mSession.beginTransaction();
}

private void manejaExcepcion(HibernateException hibernateException) {
    mTransaction.rollback();
    throw new HibernateException("ha ocurrido un error con la Base de Datos!!!", hibernateException);
}


public Conductor selectConductorByID(Integer id) {
    Conductor conductor = new Conductor();
    try{
        initQuery();
        conductor = (Conductor) mSession.get(Conductor.class, id);
    } catch (HibernateException e){
        manejaExcepcion(e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        mSession.close();
    }
    return conductor;
}
```

Please help! and thanks again!
I´m a little bit deseperated...

Comment: I don't know if this helps in any way because I don't see where your queries are and how you are calling them, but I saw [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5659027/1300817) and it says there to `call  sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);` and `sqlite3_close(database);` to finalize the compiled statements and close the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From  FAQ (5) in SQLite FAQ:

> But use caution: this locking mechanism might not work correctly
>       if the database file is kept on an NFS filesystem. This is because
>       fcntl() file locking is broken on many NFS implementations.
>       You should avoid putting SQLite database files on NFS if multiple
>       processes might try to access the file at the same time.
>       On Windows, Microsoft's documentation says that locking 
>       may not work under FAT filesystems if you are not running the Share.exe daemon.
>       People who have a lot of experience with Windows tell me that file
>       locking of network files is very buggy and is not dependable.
>       If what they say is true, sharing an SQLite database between 
>       two or more Windows machines might cause unexpected problems.

Maybe this is the cause for you problem? Are you working on windows?

> Multiple processes can have the same database open at the same time.
>       Multiple processes can be doing a SELECT at the same time.
>       But only one process can be making changes to the database
>       at any moment in time, however.

SQLLite is problematic in multi-user scenarios, but can still work fine if updates are short and fast.
In your code it looks like you are not closing the transaction correctly.
Maybe this case the db lock

You should change the code to  see hibernate doc [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html)

```
private Transaction initQuery() throws HibernateException {
    mSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    mTransaction = mSession.beginTransaction();
    return mTransaction;    
}


public Conductor selectConductorByID(Integer id) {
    Conductor conductor = new Conductor();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try{
        tx = initQuery();
        conductor = (Conductor) mSession.get(Conductor.class, id);
       //flush and commit before close
        mSession.flush();
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e){
        manejaExcepcion(e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        mSession.close();
    }
    return conductor;
}
```

Comment: I´m travelling and i hope that this weekend i´ll try the solution

Comment: I´ve done your changes and the database is still locked...

Yes, i´m working on windows, and the server where i´m going to deploy the aps is Windows too...
What can in do? change the database to other technology like mysql?

Comment: If it’s not a big issue I would try to install SQLite on Linux and see if the problem was solved, just to be on the safe side. Maybe switching to Linux will be a the solution.
Anyway MySQL or PostgreSQL can be a good open source RDBM alternative on windows. What are you planning for your application, how many users are planed etc.

Comment: there will be abot 50 users and i can´t install  linux in the server

Comment: MySql or postgres will do fine with 50 users. if you choose MySql and need transactions go with innodb tables.

Comment: At the end i´ve changed to MySql and it works great!
Thanks a lot for your help!!!!!